# Bootstrap popover next to form label

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, label, popover

I want to put a popover next to a form label. The problem is that if I include the label's `for` attribute, the popover won't open. If I remove the `for` attribute, the popover works. But, of course, the label doesn't toggle the input.

This is what I have (this version opens the popover, but it doesn't toggle the input):

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Send reports with exceptions to
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" title="Title" data-content="Content"></span>
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exceptionEmail" placeholder="Enter one or more email addresses separated by commas" required="required" />
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></span>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

How do I get both working at the same time?

Thanks!

Comment: Is [this http://jsfiddle.net/acWrJ/](http://jsfiddle.net/acWrJ/) something similar to what you are looking for? Click the span (question icon) to see the popover. It works fine here.

Comment: I don't see the `for` attribute in your code. Seems like that would be an important thing to include in a question specifically about that.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too.  Even though @Pitamber Tiwari was able to get it working in his fiddle in the comments (my adaptation that works is here: http://jsfiddle.net/pmdk7k27/), I couldn't get this to work on my page. It seems that the `for` attribute in the `<label>` tag adds an `onClick` event that interferes with Bootstrap v3.3 in a strange mysterious way.

My work around was to change to using the hover tag, which works fine:

```
$("[data-toggle='popover']").popover({
  trigger: "hover"
});
```